# Why strtol() returns -1 for very large numbers?

Tags: c, type-conversion, strtol

Why strtol() returns -1 for very large numbers in C?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    long long i = strtoll("135898539853985649864867468746876587784760", NULL, 10);
    printf("i = %lld\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: LLONG_MAX for most platforms is signed 64 bit `9223372036854775807`. That is considerably less than what you're providing. Secondly, `strtol` returns a `long` anyway, You would want to use`strtoll`, which still doesn't fit, but at least returns the proper type. There are three lines of code in this `main`, and two of them are broken. Might need to hit the text again.

Comment: You are printing a `long long` value with the format for a plain `int`.  That is misleading you. It returns `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: A long can't be more than 63 bits, which is about 19 decimal digits.
Probably, if you had bothered to capture the second argument you would see that it hasn't moved the read location.

Comment: `%d` is the wrong format specifier for `long long` leading to _undefined behavior_. Change it to `%lld`.

Comment: @gem Nothing in the C spec prevents "A long being more than 63 bits", even though it would be uncommon.

Comment: @GemTaylor The behavior in this case should be to move the read location to the end of the digit sequence, but return `LONG_MAX` and set errno to `ERANGE`.

Comment: It is always wise to ask yourself in this type of questions: What would I expect it to return?

Comment: For `strtol` you need `stdlib.h` .

Comment: Thanks for your attention, everyone. I implemented the suggested changes. The returned value of i is still -1. Can someone answer why?

Answer (score 3):

> Why strtol() returns -1 for very large numbers in C?

Code is mis-behaving due to using the wrong print specifier / variable combination.  That is *undefined behavior*.

`long long i = .... printf("i = %d\n", i);` should raise a warning with a well warning enabled compile. Save time and enable all warnings.

Use a matching print specifier / variable: [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028118/why-strtol-returns-1-for-very-large-numbers/51028462#comment89048762_51028118) [@Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028118/why-strtol-returns-1-for-very-large-numbers#comment89048860_51028118)

```
long long i = ....
...
//           vvv
printf("i = %lld\n", i);
```

---

It would make more sense to use `strtoll()` to convert a string to a `long long`

```
int main() {
    //  long long i = strtol("1358...
    long long i = strtoll("135898539853985649864867468746876587784760", NULL, 10);
    // printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("i = %lld\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Printing the value of `errno` would indicate overflow.  Testing the `endptr` would indicate if some conversion occurred.

As `strtoll()` may set `errno` to a non-zero value, set to 0 just prior to the function call to well assess the function's effect afterward and code did not inherit some earlier non-zero value.

```
    char *endptr;  
    errno = 0;
    long long i = strtoll(some_string, &endptr, 10);
    int errnum = errno;
    printf("i = %lld\n", i);
    if (some_string == endptr) {
      puts("No conversion");
    } else {
      if (errnum == ERANGE) { 
        puts("Overflow");
      } else if (errnum) {
        puts("Implementation specific error");
      } 
    }
```

Comment: "Use a matching print specifier / variable:" Credit where credit is due: @JonathanLeffler mentioned it before me (although I went into more detail).

Comment: Note that the call to `printf()` might set `errno` (it probably won't, but the standard library on Solaris used to (and probably still does) set `errno` to `ENOTTY` when the standard output was not a terminal — even though it reported no error).  You should either capture the value of `errno` (e.g. `int errnum = errno;`) immediately after the call to `strtoll()` and then test `errnum` instead of `errno`, or move the printing of the value until you've finished testing `errno`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True  `int errnum = errno;` is a good practice if code calls some function before evaluating or uses `errno` more than once.

Comment: I would also encourage you to mention in the text that it's necessary to set `errno` to zero immediately before calling `strtoll`, because you can't look at its return value to see if it failed, so you need to check errno unconditionally, so you need to make sure that if it's nonzero, it was `strtoll` that set it.  (Your code is fine, it's just not apparent why that `errno = 0` at the top is necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `strtol()` returns the correct value `LONG_MAX`. You use the wrong format string - try `printf("i = %lli\n", i);`. `%d` is for outputting an ordinary `int`.